# radio button form not sending data. what is the proper syntax?

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

what is the proper syntax for this radio button form i am POSTING. The form works fine without the radio buttons, its only when i add them, that i get an error saying, Undefined variable: where_to_search

```
<form action="" method="POST" >

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Search By:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="where_to_search" id="optionsRadios1" value="1" checked>
                     Group Name
            </label>
                <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="where_to_search" id="optionsRadios2" value="2">
                     Group Description
                </label>
            </div>
     </div>   


<input class="span2" name="keywords" id="appendedPrependedInput" size="15" placeholder="Search groups.." type="text"/><button class="btn" value="Go" type="submit">Go!</button>




</form>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show on this script? Everything looks to be correct in your markup.

Comment: Post your PHP code. You wouldn't get an undefined variable notice, you might get an undefined index notice unless you're expecting register_globals to be on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: checked = "checked" and <input type="submit"

Comment: I agree on `<input type="submit">`, but I do not think `checked="checked"` would help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the variable using $_POST:

```
$_POST['where_to_search']
```

Comment: And without _any_ PHP code posted, how do you know the OP hasn't done this already?

Comment: Because he says undefined variable, and not undefined index.

Comment: Yes, per my own comment above. But little point in answering without any facts.

Comment: From the information I have, this is the best answer I can give. If it turns out that he actually did this, then my answer is wrong and I'll vote to delete it if it is too unhelpful.